# Launch beanstalkd command at Ubuntu Boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, beanstalkd

I am working on beanstalkd on Ubuntu (Very new for me), I want to know which is good way to start beanstalkd service on ubuntu boot.

In short, I would like to execute,

> beanstalkd -b /path/to/binlog/directory -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11300

1. Using /etc/default/beanstalkd . I have added following code and reboot system (Not working)

   ```
   BEANSTALKD_LISTEN_ADDR=127.0.0.1
   BEANSTALKD_LISTEN_PORT=11300
   BEANSTALKD_BINLOG_DIR=/var/www
   DAEMON_OPTS="-l $BEANSTALKD_LISTEN_ADDR -p $BEANSTALKD_LISTEN_PORT -b $BEANSTALKD_BINGLOG_DIR"
   START=yes
   ```
2. sudo nano /etc/init/beanstalkd.conf and pasting and reboot system (Not working)

   ```
    description "simple, fast work queue"
    start on filesystem stop on runlevel [!2345]
    respawn respawn limit 5 2
    exec su nobody -c 'exec /usr/local/bin/beanstalkd'
   ```
3. By editing rc.local file under /etc/ folder. Paste my command to execute before **exit 0**  (Working fine for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a sample Upstart script in the Beanstalkd repo at https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/tree/master/adm/upstart
which differs to your own only by the start/stop and respawn lines being seperated.

The configuration of the Binlog directory, and IP address can be added to the beanstalkd.conf file easily enough.

Comment: I found some pasting problem in stack editor, but i have pasted same code in /etc/init/beanstalkd.conf file. I also added one more item. 

script
beanstalkd -b /var/www/ -l 127.0.0.01 -p 11300
end script

That works great for me.